# In Java, How to delete a row in a text file that meets search criteria?

Tags: java, arrays, text, delete-row

```
public static String findAndDeleteStudent(String qStudent)
{
    String fileName = "data/Students.txt";
    String findNumber = qStudent;
    File file = new File(fileName);
    Scanner dataText = null;
    String result="";

    try
    {
        dataText = new Scanner(file);
        while (dataText.hasNext())
        {
            String line = dataText.nextLine();
            if (line.contains(findNumber))
            {
                //System.out.println(line);
                //line.trim();
                //System.out.println(items[1]);
                System.out.println(line);

                result ="done";
            }
        }
    }
   catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
        result = "error";
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException nsf)
    {
        result = "error";
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnf)
    {
        result = "error";
    }

    return result;
}
```

I want to know the shortest way to delete the line string without re-writing the whole text file without the line string (that i want to delete).
I am able to retrieve the line as a string from the file using above code.
but can't delete. please help.

Comment: You can't access files randomly, so you have to do what you didn't want to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete Specific Line From Java Text File?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800603/delete-specific-line-from-java-text-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is small enough and you are bulk deleting, then you could always read into into a `HashMap` and run `.remove(qStudent)` (assuming the key is based on `qStudent`). Then, you can write out the `HashMap` to the file when finished with all deletes. If, however, you're only deleting one here and there, then yes, you'll have to do some form or (re)write. It is possible, though to do random access into a file if (1) each entry is the exact same size, (2) that size is known, and (3) there is a deterministic way to locate each student (unlikely, however). Then you can use a `java.io.RandomAccessFile` and its `seek` function to skip to the exact location. For larger files, if they are sorted, then you can use a `RandomAccessFile` and binary search to speed up locating the record in question. Also for large files, you can use memory mapping. The last two, however, will still require file (re)writing.

Answer (score 0):

As MarsAtomic suggested, (and Hot Licks corrected) you can't remove bytes randomly from a file.

But there are **two optimizations** possible.

---

But there is **no need to completely rewrite the file**.
If your line-to-be-deleted is halfway across the file, you don't need to touch the first half of the file. You would just need to rewrite second half of the file.

---

You can scan line by line and once you find the line, you can start copying.

But **while copying, there is no need to go line by line**, you can go for faster ways of copying by transferring large number of lines at once.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Files **can** be accessed randomly.  Files can even be modified randomly.  But files cannot have bytes added or removed from the middle without somehow rewriting the "tail" of the file.